# Convert .docx to pdf using XDocReport

Tags: java, apache-poi, freemarker, docx, xdocreport

I want to generate a PDF report using version 2.0.2 of xdocreport. The entire template uses the Calibri font size 8, but one cell in one table needs to use the Times New Roman font size 7. This cell contains only two merge fields, data for them reteieved from java using freemarker. With the current template, everything works fine.
I want to change the font in this cell to Calibri size 8. I simply tried to change the font name and font size from Times New Roman 7 to Calibri 8 in that cell in Microsoft Word. But when I tried to print the report, I got the following error:

[text of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYgT6.png)

Here's an image demonstrating the code of the current merge fields:
[Screenshot with mergefiels from the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDJMz.png)
What else can I try? I've already attempted to change the font in the docx template. I can't print the report because of the error, and the method returns null instead of bytes. I expect everything to work fine, and I should be able to get the report with a single font name and size.

Comment: This is a freemarker problem. While parsing the XML of `/word/document.xml` within the `*.docx` ZIP-archive, the parser gets a  `<` (start element tag) where it expects something else. Hard to tell where the problem is without having the `*.docx` file. Please unzip the `*.docx` file, have a look at `/word/document.xml` and post the XML code before and after line 4, column 7466. Please post XML code of at least one XML element before and one after.